# how to vary function parameters in js with all parameters being objects?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, requirejs

I'm using `requireJS` and need to vary the number of files being requested depending on condtion `a == true`.

Currently I'm doing this, which does not work:

```
// ok
var  baseRequestWidgets = $('html').attr('init') != true 
    ?  [ "text!../tmp/page/tmp_page_header_generic.html"
        ,"text!../tmp/page/tmp_page_header_specific.html"       
        ,"text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_header.html"
        ,"text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_navbar.html"
        ,"text!../tmp/page/tmp_page_footer.html"
        ]
    :  [ "text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_header.html"
        ,"text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_navbar.html"
        ]
// not ok
    , baseRequestObjects = $('html').attr('init') != true 
    ?  page_header_generic, page_header_specfic, page_widget_header, page_widget_navbar, page_footer 
    : page_widget_header, page_widget_navbar 


    require( baseRequestWidgets, function( baseRequestObjects
                                                /*
                                                  page_header_generic
                                                , page_header_specfic
                                                , page_widget_header
                                                , page_widget_navbar
                                                , page_footer 
                                                */
                                                ){ ... }
```

The problem is I cannot pass the objects to the function using `baseRequestObjects`. The files get requested correctly, but the `baseRequestObjects` doesn't work.

**Question:**
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT**:
THe error I'm getting is `page_header_generic is not defined`, so I assume my declaration of page_header_generic is done before the underlying file being requested???

**EDIT**:
Closer... RequireJS takes the `baseRequestObjects` to store the first requested file, when in fact it is a placeholder for a variable number of requested files.

So the question should be: 
**How to pass a dynamic number of object names to requireJS, when the placholder containing the x-number of  object names is misunderstood for as lone placeholder name itself?**

**EDIT:**
so this works, not sure I like it, because I'm passing nothing...

```
var baseRequestWidgets = function(trigger){
    var passBack;
    if ( trigger == "true" ){
        passBack = [     "text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_header.html"
                        ,"text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_navbar.html"
                    ];
                    } else {
        passBack = [     "text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_header.html" 
                        ,"text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_navbar.html"
                        ,"text!../tmp/page/tmp_page_header_generic.html"
                        ,"text!../tmp/page/tmp_page_header_specific.html"       
                        ,"text!../tmp/page/tmp_page_footer.html"
                    ];
            }
        return passBack;
        }   
    , getBaseRequestObjects = function( temps) {
        var objArr = [];
        for ( var i = 0; i < temps.length; i++){
            var thisString = temps[i],
            addToArray = temps[i].match(/tmp_(.*?)\.html/);
            objArr.push( addToArray[1] )
            }
        return objArr;
        }
    , baseRequestObjects
```

I needed to put this in a function, because both variables will have to be dynamic.

Then I'm calling require like this:

```
// inside my event call
var ...
    widgetsForThisRequest = baseRequestWidgets(trigger),
    baseRequestObjects = getBaseRequestObjects( widgetsForThisRequest );

require( widgetsForThisRequest,
    function( /* dynamic */ ) {
        // this will be dnyamic strings
        console.log( widgetsForThisRequest );
        // this will be dynamic objects
        console.log( baseRequestObjects );

        // loop using arguments - not sure if I like this
        for ( i = 0; i < baseRequestObjects.length; i++){
            widget = arguments[i];
            tempName = baseRequestObjects[i];
            ...
```

So I'm not passing any objects and have to set the widget by hand inside my loop using `arguments`. Seems to work, but not sure this is the way go. Anyway, there are more than 2 or 5 strings, so there will have to be more than 2 or 5 objects carrying the respective string. For now I'm ok, but if someone knows a better approach, thanks for sharing!

Comment: I've done something similar to your latest edit a few times, and although I would have implemented it somewhat differently, the concept is sound.  If it does what you need it to do, I say go with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code labeled 'not okay' does not do what you're thinking it does; You can't create variables like that.

I would just reorder your includes so that the two files you're always requesting come first, and then check for the existence of the other modules in your definition.

```
var  baseRequestWidgets = $('html').attr('init') != true 
    ?  [ "text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_header.html"
        ,"text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_navbar.html"
        ,"text!../tmp/page/tmp_page_header_generic.html"
        ,"text!../tmp/page/tmp_page_header_specific.html"       
        ,"text!../tmp/page/tmp_page_footer.html"
        ]
    :  [ "text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_header.html"
        ,"text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_navbar.html"
        ]

    require( baseRequestWidgets, function(    page_widget_header
                                            , page_widget_navbar
                                            , page_header_generic
                                            , page_header_specfic
                                            , page_footer 
                                            ){

         // page_widget_header and page_widget_navbar are always loaded

         // page_header_generic, page_header_specfic and page_footer
         // are undefined if init === true
    }
```

Comment: ok. also possible. I have a workaround, too, which I'm not to convinced about yet. See above. Feedback if you like!

Answer (score 1):

You can store all arguments in an array (of variable size) and use the [`.apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) on that function.

Comment: hm. never heard of that. Let me try.